# Can the PM block a bill by advising the Queen not to give royal assent?

Tags: united-kingdom, parliament, legislative-process, legislation, constitutional-monarchy

It appears to be unequivocal (them's the rules) if controversial (a lot of people don't like it) that for a bill that's passed both houses to pass into law it then needs [Royal Assent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Royal_assent) from the Queen & by constitutional convention the Queen always follows ministerial advice (the PM's) on this.

It seems then that should the PM wish to & be willing to do so he can prevent the new [Brexit delay bill](https://www.bbc.co.uk/news/av/uk-politics-49587770/brexit-delay-bill-backed-by-mp-s) from ever becoming law for as long as he is PM.

Is this correct?

Comment: Note that the news is that the government has given up opposing the law in the House of Lords, presumably having reached a compromise with Labour on the date of elections in return. So it seems a bit improbable that they would try to block the law at Assent. https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-49588186

Comment: @Fizz : Or maybe they're not opposing it because they know they can quash it this way & don't need to?

Comment: The news piece details that Labour will not agree to elections until after the Benn bill has received Royal Assent...

Comment: @Fizz : not a duplicate, I read that one b4 posting this one, also the answers, his question is not the same & the answer to mine isn't in the answers to his.

Comment: @fizz : irrelevant, I don't care what people 'think' he will or won't do, I'm asking about the facts of the rules.

Comment: If there's precedent, then it's clearly possible, so the answer your question is obviously yes.

Comment: @Fizz : Do you have a clear precedent then because I've not found one?

Comment: ***This is not a duplicate, I read that one b4 posting this one, also its answers, his question is not the same & the answer to mine isn't in the answers to his, you haven't actually read any of it have you just went by a quick skim of the title?

He was asking for potential consequences after it was done not if it really could be done

It's not even close to being a duplicate of that one***

Comment: I read your whole question, and I still don't see how this can be anything other than a duplicate. Instead of writing in ***bold italics*** about how the close voters are wrong, please explain the specific issues that are unaddressed by the other question. Right now, it just comes across as shouting about how unfair the world is.

Comment: @Kevin : that question & it's single answer is about the consequences of him doing it / mine is asking if the interpretation that he **can** do it is correct or not which isn't addressed in either that question or it's answer.

Comment: @Pelinore: can I direct you to this website's [code of conduct](https://politics.stackexchange.com/conduct#personal-attacks), specifically the section on friendly vs unfriendly behaviour. Personal attacks, including accusing someone of having "reading comprehension issues" or of lying, are not acceptable here. Please remember to be nice!

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff : no accusation was made, I merely offered up the only three alternatives for his 'opinion', he hasn't read the other question, he hasn't understood the other question or he's not being truthful, if any offence is drawn I can only posit that can only be because one of the less flattering options is the truth but that's hardly my fault ;p

Answer (score 5):

The answer to your question is "possibly". There is even precedent for the government advising the Queen to withhold assent, although the nearest one is pretty old (from Wikipedia).

> The last bill that was refused assent by the sovereign (on the advice of ministers) was the Scottish Militia Bill during Queen Anne's reign in 1708.

Additionally note the [news](https://www.bbc.com/news/uk-politics-49588186) regarding the Benn bill:

> The gaining of Royal Assent for the bill was a requirement that Labour leader Jeremy Corbyn said his party would need before it considered backing Mr Johnson's call for a general election.

And in response to some comments: it seems there's academic controversy whether the Queen would have to follow the advice of ministers in such a controversial matter. [On one hand](https://www.theaustralian.com.au/world/the-times/brexit-lawyers-clash-over-role-of-queen/news-story/2a3ec4b38834be8c61fe631fc46a74e2)...

> Rodney Brazier, professor of constitutional law at Manchester University, argued that it would be unconstitutional for the Queen to refuse to follow the advice of her ministers.
>
> Ultimately, he said, the constitution dictated that the monarch must do what ministers advised her to do.
>
> “Few actions more dangerous to the perceived and vital political neutrality of constitutional monarchy could be imagined,” Professor Brazier wrote, “than the Queen rejecting the government’s advice.”
>
> He added that “the convention that the Queen acts on ministerial advice is based in democracy”.

On [the other hand](https://ukconstitutionallaw.org/2013/09/25/nick-barber-can-royal-assent-be-refused-on-the-advice-of-the-prime-minster/)...

> Those who argue that the Queen should accept the advice of her Ministers do not explain at any length why they adopt this interpretation of the convention.  Perhaps the best explanation of their understanding is that they group the convention on royal assent along with the rest of the conventions surrounding the prerogative powers.  Practically all of the Queen’s prerogative powers are now exercised on the advice of Ministers, normally the Prime Minister.  The prerogative can be used to appoint ministers, declare war, annex territory, sign treaties, and many other things besides.  That the Queen no longer has any discretion about the exercise of these powers is important because it upholds democratic government.  Ministers are accountable to Parliament and, ultimately, to the electorate, for the ways they use these powers.  In the words of Walter Bagehot , a republic has insinuated itself beneath the folds of a monarchy.
>
> But does this reason justify the inclusion of royal assent within the group of prerogative powers that are exercised on ministerial advice?  It is hard to see that it does.  Now the convention is operating against democratic values, rather than upholding them.  Rather than supporting parliamentary government, it would undermine it.  The point of the convention on royal assent is to uphold the primacy of the democratic element of the constitution in the making of law.  But just as it would be undemocratic to allow one person – the Monarch – to veto legislation, so too it would be undemocratic to give this power to the Prime Minister.  In short, when presented with a bill that has passed through Parliament in a proper manner, the duty of the Monarch is to give assent – irrespective of the advice of her Ministers.  There is no room for discretion.   On its best interpretation, this is what the convention requires: if the Monarch were to accept the advice of her Prime Minister on this issue, she would be acting unconstitutionally.

Comment: Yep, 'the Scottish Militia Bill during Queen Anne's reign in 1708' I read something elsewhere recently where the crown responded to a question in a very hedged manner that I found suggestive that may not have been the last time, only the last time on public record, but I find it hard to imagine how a denial of assent might somehow **not** be in the public record, so that was a bit confusing ;/

Comment: Note that the crown also doesn't have to listen to the PM when it boils down to it (_especially_ when he is already breaking with convention)

Comment: I know the constitutional convention is she always follows ministerial (the PM''s) advice on these matters : but what convention would he be breaking by advising her not to assent, I wasn't aware there was one on what advice the PM had to give in respect to assent?

Comment: @Orangesandlemons: it seems there's a bit of scholarly debate whether the Queen can refuse to follow the advice of ministers in such a matter https://www.theaustralian.com.au/world/the-times/brexit-lawyers-clash-over-role-of-queen/news-story/2a3ec4b38834be8c61fe631fc46a74e2

Comment: "Rodney Brazier, professor of constitutional law at Manchester University, argued that it would be unconstitutional for the Queen to refuse to follow the advice of her ministers."

Comment: @Fizz : Not really, _technically_ she can but by tradition (& probably personal inclination) it seems highly unlikely she ever will (she'd probably only ever get to do it once b4 the power was taken from her anyway?), the only real question probably hinges on if he has the constitutional authority to advise her against assent (it seems likely he does but I'm not 100% sure on that point) & then if he's willing to do that, which can only be conjecture thus my limiting my question the former.

Comment: @Fizz , yeah, because he's making it up as he goes along based on how he wants it to work, rather than any particular rules. If he wants to argue that royal assent is in fact prime ministerial assent then good luck, but he's relying on slight-of-hand 'oh things changed because of custom' or whatever he's trying to claim. And once we enter that territory, well, anythings fair game, especially with activist judges

Comment: @chirlu: I think Harper got [mentioned](https://verfassungsblog.de/boris-and-the-queen-lessons-from-canada/) by analogy in the current Brexit discussion for his use of prorogation.

Comment: It might come down to the theory behind the PM's ability to make the recommendation. If it's because of his position as the chair of the executive committee of the Privy Council, perhaps a plenary of the Privy Council could make its own recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

It is convention that the Queen normally acts on the advice of her Ministers - unless there is more specific convention that requires her to do otherwise.

In this context, the more specific convention is that the Queen grants Royal Assent to a Bill passed by both Houses of Parliament. That convention is superior to the convention that she follow the advice of her Ministers. It has been more than three centuries since a monarch refused Royal Assent.

> When bills, either public or private, or Church of England Measures
>   (on which see paras 31.46 –31.49 ), have been finally agreed to by
>   both Houses, they await only the Royal Assent to be declared to
>   Parliament to give them, as Lord Chief Justice Hale says, ‘the
>   complement and perfection of a law’,1 and assent must be forthcoming.

https://erskinemay.parliament.uk/section/5552/royal-assent/

But that is *Royal Assent* - there is also *Queen's Consent*.

Queen's Consent may come into play if the Bill would significantly affect the 'prerogative powers', e.g. the power to agree international treaties, and there has been some debate about this with regard to the recent Brexit delay bill.

Comment: Queen's Consent, not Royal Consent. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queen%27s_Consent

Comment: @SteveMelnikoff Oops!

Comment: A lot of people have fallen victim to this one. :-)